# If browsers can zoom now, why should we use em instead of px?

Tags: css

I've often seen people say that using 'em's is a better idea because it works better when people need to change their default font size.

But I've never heard of anyone changing their font size. However, I've heard of people (and done myself) zooming in and out. Zooming in and out works fine.

Are 'em's obsolete? Can I finally go back to pixels? Or do people still change the default font size? And if they do, do pixels still break when people change the font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, em's are good in css when you want to create custom scalable buttons, you see. If you used pixels for the padding, then you'll be in for a heck of measurements, while if you used em's, the padding would dynamically scale in size according to the size of the font.

Comment: But when I use the zoom on my browser, the buttons look fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Verdagon Well, the use of `em` is not all about zooming, for example, when you want to have different sized custom buttons for different uses, `em` makes it much easier to make any size of buttons you like.

Comment: Yes, you can also use % and it accomplishes the same thing. Ems are used for salable designs, like fluid designs!

Comment: Instead of designing a button using 1.5em and one using 2.0em, couldn't someone just use 30px and 40px?

Comment: @Verdagon because if you changed the font size of the button, you will have to modify the padding accordingly if you used pixels, but if you used em, you won't have to modify a thing, other than the font size of the button.

Comment: I see! So we can use that one hardcoded value up there to crank up or down all the sizes inside the widget... quite brilliant. Good to see ems still have some use. djthorns, is there anything ems can do that % can't do?

Comment: @Verdagon Erm... not really... I'm not really sure about `%`, but `em` links to the font size of a specific element, so `em` should be foolproof....

Comment: Oh, dunno what I'm thinking. em references the current font size, % references the containing element's width or height, unless you're specifying a font-size rule. Is that right?